# How to open the TextEdit app using BlueJ on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, bluej, textedit

So i'm working on a small program, and I need to open the TextEdit application through my program. I know there are many ways out there, but I just need a few lines of code (like 2 or 3) that will help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open /Applications/TextEdit.app");

Comment: I had to do a try and catch exception, but thank you so much